# CSS issue with hover psuedo class

Tags: css, hover

Im having an issue having a link that when i hover it should display a div I have set up, the basic CSS looks like so,

```
#adiv { 
max-height: 50px;
max-width: 50px;
z-index: 5;
display: none;
background-color: red;
}


#a:hover + #adiv {
display: block;

}

#a:hover {
color: white;
}
```

"#a" is a basic anchor element and lights up white when hovered as my code suggests, when i turn "#adiv" display back to block manually I can see the red square, really not sure what could be disrupting it from showing. I can post the HTML if required, I have it also on codepen http://codepen.io/Keiffy101/pen/aOWJZa any assistance appreciated, I'm a bit of an amature as it seems it should be straight forward.

thanks Keiffy101

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#a:hover + #adiv {
display: block;

}
```

This will not work as it assume that `#a` is a direct sibling of `#adiv`...in other words that `#adiv` **immediately** follows `#a` in your HTML....and it doesn't.

In fact, given your current HTML structure, there is no way for hovering over `#a` to affect `#adiv` as the two elements do not share a common parent.

[**30 CSS Selectors to Memorize**](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048)